How to run function in nextjs on router.push complete
I'm using event bus with mitt library and I want to listen to logout even and when it occurs, call:
  useEventBus('logout', () => {
    router.replace('/');
    toast({ variant: 'success', title: 'Wylogowano!' });
    setIsLoggingOut(false);
  });

where setIsLoggingOut sets a global variable in my axios interceptor. I want to call setIsLoggingOut once router.replace() completes and not as it is done now. How can I do that?
